# How to add custom validation rules in Magento-2

Tags: magento-2.1, validation

I have written `rule.js` file in following path.

**app/design/frontend/package/theme/Magento_Ui/web/js/lib/validation/rule.js**

add following code in **rule.js**

```
"mobiletendigit": [
        function(value) {
            return value.length > 9 &&  value.length < 11 
            && value.match(/^(?:(?:\+|0{0,2})91(\s*[\ -]\s*)?|[0]?)?[789]\d{9}|(\d[ -]?){10}\d$/);
        },
        $.mage.__('Please specify a valid 10 digits mobile number')
        ]
```

add **mobiletendigit** class to input field.

```
<input type="text" name="telephone" value="<?php echo $block->escapeHtml($block->getAddress()->getTelephone()) ?>" title="<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo __('Phone Number') ?>" class="input-text required-entry mobiletendigit validate-digits <?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $this->helper('Magento\Customer\Helper\Address')->getAttributeValidationClass('telephone') ?>" id="telephone" data-validate="{required:true, 'mobiletendigit':true}">
```

add following **tag to form**.

```
data-mage-init='{"validation":{}}'
```

Answer (score 4):

Use like below code...

1) In input or select tag add our validaion with this code

```
data-validate="{required:true, 'validate-custom-name':true}"
```

2) Add js validation for “Validate-custom-name”

validation script

```
<script type="text/javascript">
require([
'jquery', // jquery Library
'jquery/ui', // Jquery UI Library
'jquery/validate', // Jquery Validation Library
'mage/translate' // Magento text translate (Validation message translte as per language)
], function($){ 
$.validator.addMethod(
'validate-custom-name', function (value) { 
return (value !== 'test'); // Validation logic here
}, $.mage.__('Enter Valid name'));

});
</script>
```

Comment: hi kisan, validate-custom-name should be validate-mobiletendigit...

Comment: Yes. But it is just for example. You can use your own.

Comment: <script type="text/javascript">
require([
'jquery', // jquery Library
'jquery/ui', // Jquery UI Library
'jquery/validate', // Jquery Validation Library
'mage/translate' // Magento text translate (Validation message translte as per language)
], function($){ 
$.validator.addMethod(
'validate-mobiletendigit', function (value) { 
return (value !== '7715878743'); // Validation logic here
}, $.mage.__('Enter Valid name'));

});
</script>
i am using this but not working

Answer (score 2):

1. Define this Js Code in view file :

   ```
   <script type="text/javascript">
     require([
     'jquery',
     'jquery/ui',
     'jquery/validate',
     'mage/translate'
     ], function($){ 
     $.validator.addMethod(
     'mobile-number-validation', function (value) { 
         var re = /^(?:(?:\+|0{0,2})91(\s*[\ -]\s*)?|[0]?)?[789]\d{9}|(\d[ -]?){10}\d$/;
         return !re.test(value);

     }, $.mage.__('Please specify a valid 10 digits mobile number.'));
     }); 
   </script>
   ```
2. Now Just Add Validation Class in input field .

   ```
   <input type="text" class="mobile-number-validation" name="telephone" data-validate="{required:true}"/>
   ```

Comment: hi Sujeet its working but every time displaying wrong message

Comment: hi sujeet i want to add this on rule.js

Comment: @ErSarveshVTiwari what message it is showing ? Or May be check the pattern is correct OR not for 10 digits mobile number?

Comment: its working fine. i am looking its validation for knockout js page

Answer (score 1):

#### It could help someone !

Un exemple for à phone number who contains exactly `10 digits` and begin with `06` or `07` :

**Field :**

```
<input type="phone" name="phone" id="phone" value="<?= $block->escapeHtmlAttr($block->getFormData()->getPhone()) ?>" title="<?= $block->escapeHtmlAttr(__('Phone')) ?>" class="input-text" data-validate="{required:true, 'validate-mobilePhoneNumber':true}">
```

**Js condition:**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    require([
        'jquery', 'jquery/ui', 'jquery/validate', 'mage/translate', 'mage/mage'
    ], function($){
        $.validator.addMethod(
            'validate-mobilePhoneNumber', function (value) {
                return /^0(6|7)[0-9]{8}$/.test(value);
            }, $.mage.__('Please enter a mobile phone number. Ex 06******** ou 07********.'));

    });
</script>
```